# Spring Boot : Kotlin & MongoRepository : Performing a full text search

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mongodb, mongorepository

Hi there I am really new to Spring Boot and using Kotlin to learn it (I do Android/iOS professionally etc)

I have a basic API setup (Spring Boot, Web, MongoDB etc) and my interface uses **MongoRepository**

I have set up my MongoDB with a full-text index (text1) and sort by score.  I am trying to call it in Kotlin now

```
override fun searchResult(search : String): List<Result> {

    val criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage()
            .matchingAny(search)

    val query = TextQuery.queryText(criteria)
            .sortByScore()
            .with(PageRequest(0, 5))

    var r : List<Result> =  searchRepository.findAll(query, Result.class)
}
```

How do I actually execute the query?  FindAll is not right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a query method in the repository interface. Please refer to repository [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) for details